# Error "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Valid arities are: [1], but 4 arguments provided." on dynamic input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a form dynamically using jquery with the following code

```
function createFieldSet(dataArray) {
    var fieldset = $('fieldset');

    $.each(dataArray, function(key, value) {
        for(var key in value) {
            if (key.toLowerCase() === "other") {
                fieldset.append($('<button/>').attr({ type: 'button', name:'btn_' + key, value: key}).on('click', 'textOther', function() {alert('click');}).html(value[key]));
                fieldset.append($('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name:'textOther', value: ""}).hide);
            } else {
                fieldset.append($('<button/>').attr({ type: 'button', name:'btn_' + key, value: key}).html(value[key]));
            }

            fieldset.append('<br />');
        }
    });     
}
```

but returns an error shown in the title, pointing to the second line that appends the input line, which I'm trying to have hidden on creation unless the button created above is clicked. Was wondering why I'd get something referring to animate when I didn't call such a function, and if this is fixable/doable....or if this should have been done in a server side language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the missing parentheses on `hide`, here

```
fieldset.append(
    $('<input/>').attr({ 
        type: 'text', 
        name:'textOther', 
        value: ""
    }).hide
);
```

should be

```
fieldset.append(
    $('<input/>').attr({ 
        type: 'text', 
        name:'textOther', 
        value: ""
    }).hide()
);
```

but it's a funky syntax and you should be writing it

```
fieldset.append(
    $('<input />', { 
        type  : 'text', 
        name  : 'textOther', 
        value : ""
        css   : {
            display : 'none'
        }
    })
);
```

The reason it happens is because jQuery has the following internal function

```
jQuery.each([ "toggle", "show", "hide" ], function( i, name ) {
    var cssFn = jQuery.fn[ name ];
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( speed, easing, callback ) {
        return speed == null || typeof speed === "boolean" ?
            cssFn.apply( this, arguments ) :
            this.animate( genFx( name, true ), speed, easing, callback );
    };
});
```

where jQuery is actually looking for the property `hide`, and it picks it up somehow from you adding `.hide` to the object, I won't search the source any further for exactly why it's happening, as it's just a typo on your part really, and not that interesting.

Comment: It's always the small things that trip you up. Thanks I'll give this a try.

Comment: Small typos can be horrible, especially when it doesn't just throw an error but actually works, just not like intended and you end up having an error further down the line that is hard to track. In this case the missing parentheses doesn't throw an error, it's actually valid, but jQuery picks up the property and runs the posted loop, and errors out when the arguments for the `animate` function doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you used

```
fieldset.append(
    $('<input/>').hide
);
```

But it should be

```
fieldset.append(
    $('<input/>').hide()
);
```

This second code runs the function [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and returns the element, so you can append it.